# Time intervals or scheduling option in Gmail mail merge via Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, mailmerge

I want a google script that allows me to send emails via Gmail mail merge after intervals of  5 mins or allows me to schedule it.
I don't know how to code and it will be really helpful for me if someone can help me in this regard or tell me how to do this.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

#### A Start

```
function createTBTrigger() {
  if (ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().filter(t => t.getHandlerFunction() == "lfunko").length == 0) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger("lfunko").timeBased().everyMinutes(5).create();
  }
}

function lfunko() {
  GmailApp.sendEmail('me@mydomain.com','Subject','Message');
}
```